# Twin.Macro (Styled Components) + Typescript in NextJS : Argument of type 'Interpolation<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components, tailwind-css, template-strings

[Just followed the twin.macro tutorial](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/next-styled-components#installation) to set it up with `next.js`, `styled-components` & `typescript`. Followed everything in a newly setup project, but I'm getting this error:

> ./components/GlobalStyles.tsx:7:36
> Type error: Argument of type 'Interpolation' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemeProps>'.
> Type 'InterpolationFunction' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemeProps>'.
> Type 'InterpolationFunction' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemeProps>'.
> Type 'ThemeProps' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Seems to have to do with this line here in [GlobalStyles.tsx](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/next-styled-components#add-the-global-styles):

```
const CustomStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: ${theme`colors.purple.500`} <=== this line
    ${tw`antialiased`}
  }
`;
```

but I'm not sure what to do about it, since I've followed everything to the dot?

edit:
full GlobalStyles.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import tw, { theme, GlobalStyles as BaseStyles } from "twin.macro";
 

const CustomStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: ${theme`colors.purple.500`} 
    ${tw`antialiased`}
  }
`;

const GlobalStyles = () => (
  <>
    <BaseStyles />
    <CustomStyles />
  </>
);

export default GlobalStyles;
```

Comment: Can you add your full `GlobalStyles.tsx` file?

Comment: It's exactly the file that I link to above (in the twin.macro documentation), but I'll put it in here anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed this error:

```js
...
const CustomStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: ${theme<string>('colors.purple.500')} // <-- the fix
    ${tw`antialiased`}
  }
...
`;
```